# Can we raise two Pull request for master branch concurrently

Tags: git, github, devops, git-bash, pull-request

I have a confusion with GIT.
Query -
I have Feature1 and Feature2 branch cloned from MASTER branch. Respective changes and code has been committed and synced to respective branch in a GIT BASH

```
For Feature 1
git checkout master
git pull origin master
---resolve conflicts if any
git checkout Feature1
git merge master
```

Raised a Pull Request 1 for Feature 1 branch to move changes to Master (Feature1 ---> Master)
At the time of raising PR, *Should I wait for Pull request 1 to be approved and completed before raising Pull Request 2 for feature 2 branch*

```
For Feature 2
git checkout master
git pull origin master
---resolve conflicts if any
git checkout Feature2
git merge master
```

OR
*Can I raise PR simultaneously for both the Feature branch and expect that there will be no merge conflicts.*

My Understanding - I always think that this will create a issue because my Feature 2 branch PR will not be having the latest commit from master branch which was moved after the PR for Feature 1 branch was approved.
Please let me know if this will be an issue. I want to know the understanding for having two PR raised parallelly. I have searched for same queries but none has given me the lucid understanding.

Comment: You can't simultaneously approve and merge both in one go, so one of them will have to be approved or merged after the other, and this *may* introduce a conflict. If changes in the first merged branch conflicts with the second branch, then there will be a conflict.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the clarification. I believe the same. In my team, 2 different team member has raised their PR simultaneously. Then there is a high possibility of conflict. That's why I always had this doubt that Is this even possible. Is this issue qualify as a limitation in git.

Comment: There shouldn't *automatically* be a high chance of conflict just because of the timing, unless you have a project where you always have to modify the same files in the same places. If you do, then you should work on refactoring those files so that you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### multiple pull-requests are normal

Having multiple pull-requests at the same time open is completely normal and even medium sized projects would grind to an halt if this was not possible.

In most cases you don't even get any conflicts when merging. And should 2 PR change the same lines then you will get a merge conflict for the second PR. You can just fix it and push the updated branch to update the PR.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what if PR2 is not having the changes of PR1 (not up to date with master) then at that time when the PR2 is approved then PR1 changes which has just moved to master branch will be lost ? Is the understanding right ? Cause this can happen if there is 2 PR raised parallelly or Git handles it ? Please help me to understand this ..

Comment: The answer to that depends a bit on how you "merge" the PR. The easiest to explain is to merge it into master. And in a merge git will combine the changes from both sides. Just try it out locally. Init git in a new folder and commit a file with some lines of text. Create two branches and change in each a different line. Now merge both branches back to master. maybe try it a second time with changes in the same line.